# Scale Flex Items with Flex container to keep relative scale?

Tags: html, css, blazor

I'm building a page in html and the page looks fine and does great on desktop it looks like this
[Desktop Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhuPM.png)

but then when I scale it all down the text container is forced out and then is smaller as seen here

[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AawHv.png)

The struggle is that i've tried a bunch of things (see a list below) and none of them seem to work!

Here is what the structure of the items looks like, completly encased in a flex-container

```
 <div class="card" data-tilt data-tilt-max="15" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-glare data-tilt-scale="1.15" data-tilt-max-glare="0.5">
  <img src="/Coach Placeholder.png" alt="Coach">
  <div class= "container">

      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>

      <p> Football Coach </p>

  </div>
```

and the @media call

```
     @@media (max-width: 780px) {
    .flex-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .card{
        max-width:75%;
    }

    h4{
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align:left;
}

p{
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    text-align:left;
}

}
```

I just can't get anything to force the text to be bigger, i've tried changing the font size already too.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You've set your font size to be dependent on the viewport width by using `vw` units. Each `vw` unit is 1% of the viewport's width. So a desktop may be 1920px wide, therefore 1vw would be equal to 19.2px. A mobile display would have somewhere around 640px which would make 1vw equal to 6.4px.

If you would like retain the size of the text I would recommend using `rem` or `px`.
While `rem` is a relative unit, `px` is an absolute unit.
You can read more about them on the [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CodeBorgg/pen/RwVeLVM) that I made for you to have a look at.